# Vertically & Horizontally center align text

Tags: html, css

I have 2 block areas on my website.

I'd like to vertically and horizontally align the text centrally on both areas. Right now it sits below :(

Here is my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/byp0pevr/

```css
.text-block div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    z-index: 5;
}

#adbox1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 620px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}

#adbox2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 320px;
}

.image-holder {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.image-holder:after {
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
}
.image-holder:hover:after {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div id="adbox1" class="image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x620" title="1">
  <div class="text-block">
    <div>Some<br>Text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="adbox2" class="image-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" title="1">
  <div class="text-block">
    <div>Some<br>Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give  `position: relative;` to `#adbox1` and give following css.

```
.text-block {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byp0pevr/1/)**